How to prevent virtual keyboard from moving entire page upward in react/next?

As you can see, in react/next - on Safari the virtual keyboard pushes the whole page up, which I don't want.

I've tried different meta viewport tags to no avail, ive tried setting a useEffect to adjust for the height of the keyboard and that was really glitchy. I've tried putting overflow and setting min-heights on the outer divs and nothing is working.
Has anyone else had this problem with react/next on safari and how did they solve it? The whole page is pushing up when you click the text-input.
